# Can we get more people in ##mathematica (the irc channel) on freenode?

Tags: discussion

It's like the only popular language's channel that is just totally dead... It would be great to have it be more populated for general low-level questions that would be clutter on SE, and also would get rid of all the debugging help questions on here.

Comment: Have you seen [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and what are the advantages of freenode compared to it?

Comment: See also http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#irc

Comment: IRC is just really easy, most languages have a highly active channel.

Comment: I disagree that IRC is really easy. I used to use it some years ago, but always found the commands to create a channel, change modes, or even set up authentication to be seriously inconvenient. It is certainly not impossible or even particularly difficult when one gets used to it, but these arcane commands, plus the severe social consequences of minor etiquette infractions in most IRC rooms, do not make it an entirely pleasant experience and must be a huge barrier to entry for many people.

Comment: IRC etiquette is definitely a pain, even between channels- but it's completely established by the mods, and #mathematica doesn't /have/ to be like that. Also, I'm willing to help anyone that wants to get accustomed to IRC things. Hexchat is a good beginner's client, and all you would have to run is "/connect freenode", "/join ##mathematica", and "/nick $username" to get to the channel, where people can help you get set up better.

Comment: What's IRC? Or should I be asking what's freenode?

Comment: IRC is sorta a protocol for internet chat, and freenode is a network of servers that hosts this protocol.

Answer (score 10):

I think there is one big reason why that IRC channel will never take off and why the StackExchange chat is vastly superior:

Chat channels for small communities start off slow. There won't be a high traffic at the beginning.  That means that people who ask need to wait for the answer, possibly wait for many hours, even a full day.  People who can answer need to see old messages, messages sent many hours ago.  In practice they both need to be connected 24/7.  Yes, that's possible and many people do it.  If you have access to a non-stop running Linux server, you can run [irssi with screen](https://quadpoint.org/articles/irssi/), provided you're not intimidated by the terminal interface ... (most people are).  But most people just won't do this.  I won't take the trouble to set everything up, I don't have the patience or time for it.

Compare this with the StackExchange chat: you open it, and you can see the last message right away, whether you were offline before or not.  IRC just doesn't have this.  It has various imperfect workarounds, none of which have the convenience of what SE chat offers.

The ##mathematica channel has existed for many years now and IMO this is the main reason it was never able to take off.

Comment: i mean, weechat+screen on a raspi is fast and easy, but still looked scary to me just a year ago. I didn't know stackexchange had a chat, but either way, i'd love to activity in ##mathematica!

Comment: @laudiacay I think the best you can do to help that IRC channel is to join it, stay online as long as possible, discuss, answer questions.  You can consider setting up a chatlog for it too, if you are ambitious.

Comment: I gotchu. Might set up the chatlog this summer, though I'm not sure where I would host that. I can also add an instance of an ircbot that me and a few friends wrote, You should join too!